# Redux Tookit non-serializable when returning a URL as the response

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

In my app I am trying to save an image to S3. I make a request to get the presigned url and then I use that URL to save the image. Here is my reducer action:

```
export const createPicture = ({ imageBlob, mimeType }) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(createPictureLoading())
  
  try {
    const { fileName, url } = await Api.createPutPresignedUrl(mimeType)

    await Api.savePictureToS3(url, imageBlob)

    dispatch(createPictureComplete())
  } catch(err) {
    dispatch(createPictureFailed(err))
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

`A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path:`payload`. Value: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400]`

The URL returned looks like this:

`https://myApp.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/feebe2e0-1293-46f9-83fa-f7dfb462d5f3-04112023-4d61757d-2a45-406c-bc82-0f92dbdfe51d?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=ASIASQSV6K4XFEF6FEJR%2F20230411%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230411T141707Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEL%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCrUoZAFyEKS4BCTiC%2Bc298MJOywegp8EExUm2xq2VDgQIhAOqCCbuJYTHcCjt6zcUAYjPqRvXYIQuuV1v4MF%2FGRE0CKpEDCKf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBBoMMTczMDUyNjc5OTgyIgyan6%2B9HGuZJ3fHl%2BQq5QLc3jmhPrlENi3dO%2BbfRMew2trBIgFh%2F9%2BMkgIYp1tTuUOhI9mNvDZOh8sK1CSgH7Wa%2BFKlZnLIQRfbUIyGviltCiF%2BtdHdh9gH2Y7HxxAbHmDFxk09oYMp4R4prHey1QX4KAY6ALG5ZGjphOKmDiyWmM4rPo06qotZhQhg03fKfY1cxP1%2F3nw0wES5KCRTCihqx2aZDkllWZSyDNw63uzjGBe0NkOxWIZ1FA8xczwa7cVU4zosMDhbxHFBdTv0V5h6QUPDgBqU4A4%2FMhaRHHvSa9V07MX8fBS2khC8wo1Xz1VYdig2nH6L1UKBeoPwvKM1hofHcuv0UW%2BRDU4q56PBbhlhIEmiUdTTsXF8pbssk4n7eoEU2nLAHGD%2B11vdRwDtSR6SpP6N9mJEo7Om%2BCBv5%2Fc1zjGLcgXSUxzuCuuP0UbQETPr9XgSvqkipDobIaBJ%2FkfHNGj8htihiSTH6tEOiF%2FOBWgw1NTVoQY6nQHffd9BbvpYEShOp9lDnPwBxzJhxKPA%2FJ0H3dm1bVH%2Fym2CQMfLviJhr4LYr1UIEG60FTgO03Yv23mg8uGNtvdrMu8BFZQDASwXwPw6Z1WMFlEfe7FVKDWQthWBzDFA7aiHtx%2BhnvISzo31PTehEhHyvUALZhdMdXCKJW1RKxnEpc6MHPiR3jU6OQtt6Tj7k5txK2Hyd1LGV8sujWn7&X-Amz-Signature=0658ac9f99b27e4a7c8fzdf87996f441acf9a0c3d260437ae44a3ac54fd593c0&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=PutObject`

I tried using `decodeURI(url)` to see if this would stop the error but it didn't. How should I handle a url as the payload from one API call, to use in the next API call?